# What is 一個 in Japanese used in context of cooking?

Tags: counters, food

On cookpad.com, it says "chicken broth 一個", even though I'm pretty sure chicken broth is a liquid... So what does it mean here? A tablespoon, a teaspoon? An arbitrary figure?

Actual words for reference:

> チキンコンソメ1個

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this context (and many contexts regarding cooking at home), チキンコンソメ1個 refers to *a cube of* chicken broth -- something like magi bouillon.

cf. [クノール® チキンコンソメ](http://www.ajinomoto.co.jp/products/detail/?ProductName=knorr_consomme_1)

Comment: I hope I'm making myself clear by just saying *a cube of*. Broth, thickened into cubic shapes, and you dissolve it in hot water when cooking.

Comment: Damn, I didn't even know that cubes of chicken broth existed O.o, thanks :D

Comment: Usually in English it's called bouillon when it's dried and after you reconstitute it it becomes broth.